# On executing PHP i get NULL value

Tags: php, mysql

When i select 3 value in "$result" in my PHP then i get last three row value "NULL".

```
<?php
include "seminit.php";
$result1 = $_POST["result"];
$semno = $_POST["semno"];
$slotno= $_POST["slotno"];
$tdat=date("d/m/Y")."  /  ".$slotno;
$sql1="alter table $semno add `".$tdat."` varchar(30)";
$conn->query($sql1);
$arr = (explode(",",$result1));
$len = count($arr);
$query = "SELECT name FROM $semno";
$res = $conn->query($query);
$array = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
{
    //$response["data"] = array();    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
   {
        $array[] = $row["name"];
        //array_push($response["data"], $user);
    }
}
$len1 = count($array);
$res=array_intersect($arr,$array);
$res1=array_diff($array,$arr);
print_r($res1);
print_r($res);
$relen=count($res);
$relen1=count($res1);
$present="Present";
$absent="Absent";
for($i=0;$i<$relen;$i++)
{
    $sql = "update $semno set `$tdat`='$present' where `name`='$res[$i]'";
    $conn->query($sql);
}
for($j=0;$j<$relen1;$j++)
{
    $sql = "update $semno set `$tdat`='$absent' where `name`='$res1[$j]'";
    $conn->query($sql);
}
$response["success"] = array();
$response["success"] = 1;
echo(json_encode($response));
?>
```

[This is my output of PHP.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk3O4.jpg)

And on server i am getting this type of value,

[And this is how my database is looking.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjYTI.jpg)

So as you can see there is "NULL" is last three row so when i enter three value in $result object then i get three null value.
So please anyone can help me out with this problem.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: do array_filter($relen) and array_filter($relen1) you may have empty elments in these arrays you're looping.\

Comment: You should not concatenate user input into SQL queries, you should use [prepared statments](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to avoid SQL injection